# django: filtering on undefined number of options

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to process undefined number of filtering options given to a views (in a post request).

For example if we have a view:

def get_posts_by_category(request):
    print request.POST

```
if request.POST:
    categories = [Categories.objects\
                  .get(cat=item) for item in request.POST["category"].split(",")[:-1]]
```

so view takes a list of categories, which can consist from 1 - n items.

Could someone suggest how can I get all articles, with categories I've got from POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Article.objects.filter(category__in=request.POST.getlist('category'))
```

Comment: slightly offtopic: doesn't direct use of POST variables in a query pose a security risk?

Comment: No, everything is automatically escaped before being sent to the DB, so no risk of query injection.